# NSS 32 bit package on Java 64 bit

Tags: java, nss

I have Windows 7 with 64 bit environment.
Configuring gateway,

I run NSS3.12.4 32 bit on 64 bit platform and got this error.

**Libnspr4.dll Can't load IA 32 bit .dll on AMD 64 bit platform**

Java is 64 bit. How to get NSS 64 bit package?
Is there any way to fix this error if I will work with NSS 32 bit?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a simpler answer, but you could download the sources and build them to create a shared library for your platform:

- [JSS information](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JSS)
- [NSS & PSM Downloads](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/src/download.html)
- [NSS Build instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NSS_reference/Building_and_installing_NSS/Build_instructions).

Comment: Yes. Build with `USE_64=1` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do that on 64bit Windows OS.
In order to use NSS on Java, you need to go through SunPKCS11 provider, which is according to Sun [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html):

> The Sun PKCS#11 provider is supported on Solaris (SPARC and x86) and
>   Linux (x86) in both 32-bit and 64-bit Java processes. It is also
>   supported on 32-bit Windows (x86) but not currently on 64-bit Windows
>   platforms due to the lack of suitable PKCS#11 libraries.